# Application calls another Application. Does it create another process?

Tags: process, operating-system

I was reading about Processes. I wan't to know what really happens. My situation :
"I opened an Application. That creates a process say process1. I have other applications interfaced with this one and all these open up when i click a button inside my running application. I want to know Does my process1 create new processes and IPC happens OR processes for all the linked applications are created at once and then IPC happens?"

Comment: @user3344003 : I am learning about processes and threads and was wondering what really happens when my application is interfaced to another application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously,a running application is a bunch of processes,or maybe a single process which has internally multiple threads acting within these processes.

So,your activity decides the creation and deletion of processes.say,if you are running an application such as media player and you suddenly start searching related info about the album---so here,totally a new process is created which helps interaction through web and after returning the output,it may die,may not,but the process was created on your request.Also,mostly ipc happens within processes,exactly as per your thinking,but shared memory communication is also one of the option,which is complicated and is less common.

One more thing to point out is that there are several 'daemon processes' which are running in the background and don't die before shutdown instruction!So,these processes are also sometimes related to the running application and serves its request.But,mostly,newer processes are created when we switch our task or perform certain action in the application.